# Qt - Show GIF on QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, animation

Good evening. I wrote this function expecting a GIF inside of the QLabel inside of the QDialog, as written below. It appears and works as intended... Kinda.

I'd like the QDialog to be adjusted to the size of the GIF. I think magic constants aren't the best, so I don't use QDialog::setGeometry() yet.

What I ask:

- How do I get size of the GIF?
- With the size obtained, is QDialog::setGeometry() the correct function?

  ```
  void MainWindow::on_listOfURL_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
  {
      QDialog* d = new QDialog(this);
      QLabel* lab = new QLabel(d);
      QMovie* selectedGif = new QMovie("C:/test.gif", QByteArray(), lab);
      lab->setMovie(selectedGif);
      d->show();
      selectedGif->start();
  }
  ```

[Output of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPdeP.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1. After look to the documentation guess that `selectedGif->scaledSize()` or `selectedGif->currentPixmap().size()` can return the needed size (didn't check). 2. `setGeometry` sets position too; `resize` or `setFixedSize` may be a better choice. 3. Your dialog doesn't fit the label to it's contents as you don't assign any layout.

Comment: @ilotXXI At first it didn't work. Then, I put those two function calls below `selectedGif->start();` and now works, though the GIF is not resizing.

Comment: It means that `currentPixmap` is set when you run the "movie". What does "GIF is not resizing" mean?

Comment: @ilotXXI it means that I can't manage to make it adjust to a fixed 'QLabel'.